# How can I do an hierarchy using 3 combo boxes in C# and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 3 combo boxes that use a data source obtained from a SQL Server Express table and they are linked with each other. For example:

combo box 1 = university (oxford, cambridge);
combo box 2 = course (biology, computer science); combo box 3 = classes (algorithms, database)

when the user chooses "oxford" in combo box 1, then only the courses of oxford must appear in combo box 2 (lets suppose biology and computer science); then, when the user chooses the course, only the classes of that specific course must appear in combo box 3.

the problem is: when the user changes the university that have been chosen before, the data source of the other 2 combo boxes aren't following the right way.... I'm using the combo box event called "selected index changed"

when the user selects another option in combo box 1, it triggers the event of changing combo box 1, then combo box 2 is updated, but before it shows the correct option inside it, it triggers the event of changing its index and then combo box 3 tries to update using the wrong infos about combo box 2... making a mess

```
    private void comboBoxUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxCourse.DataSource = valuesComboBoxes.GetCourse(comboBoxUniversity.Text);
        comboBoxCourse.DisplayMember = "name_Course";
        comboBoxCourse.Update();
    }

    private void comboBoxCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxClasses.DataSource = valuesComboBoxes.GetClasses(comboBoxUniversity.Text, comboBoxCourse.Text);
        comboBoxClasses.DisplayMember = "name_Classes";
        comboBoxClasses.Update();
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: sorry, I edited it right now... if you need anymore information to be able to help me, please just ask :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you set `ComboBox.DataSource` the `SelectedIndexChanged` gets triggered. Hence your problem. Should instead first set `DisplayMemeber` and then `DataSource`.

```
private void comboBoxUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxCourse.DisplayMember = "name_Course";
    comboBoxCourse.DataSource = valuesComboBoxes.GetUnidade(comboBoxUniversity.Text);
    comboBoxCourse.Update();
}

private void comboBoxCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxClasses.DisplayMember = "name_Classes";
    comboBoxClasses.DataSource = valuesComboBoxes.GetClasses(comboBoxUniversity.Text, comboBoxCourse.Text);
    comboBoxClasses.Update();
}
```

Comment: the problem continues :(

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you get an error? If so please post that information.

Comment: I recorded a little video showing what happens when I use your advice.. The program is in portuguese, but I think it will help you to help me hehehe
https://www.useloom.com/share/30e5af9794c64b39b1d5f05824215f67

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant; I meant what happens within your code. You should debug and see the values. It's difficult to tell without knowing what your GetUnidade() and GetClasses() methods look like. What I can gather is that somehow when you click the Universities combo for the second time the above methods don't return appropriate values.

Comment: You gathered right... GetUnidade() is GetCourse()...

public DataTable GetCourse(string university)
{
 connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        DataTable course = new DataTable("Course");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name_Course FROM Course WHERE id_University = (SELECT id_University FROM University WHERE name_University = '" + university + "') ORDER BY name_Course", connection))
        {
         connection.Open();
                course.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        connection.Close();
        return course;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a blank item as the first item on the dropdowns saying "select university", then for second "select course" and "select class" for third  or whatever with a value of zero, then this (will be very explicit for this example):

```
private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((int)cb1.SelectedValue == 0)
    {
        cb2.DataSource = new List<ComboBoxItem> { new ComboBoxItem() { Text = "select course", Value = 0 } };
        cb3.DataSource = new List<ComboBoxItem> { new ComboBoxItem() { Text = "select class", Value = 0 } };
    }
    else
    {
        cb2.DataSource = GetCoursesForUniversity((int)cb1.SelectedValue);
        cb3.DataSource = new List<ComboBoxItem> { new ComboBoxItem() { Text = "select class", Value = 0 } };
    }
}

private void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((int)cb1.SelectedValue == 0)
    {
        cb3.DataSource = new List<ComboBoxItem> { new ComboBoxItem() { Text = "select class", Value = 0 } };
    }
    else
    {
        cb3.DataSource = GetClassesForCourse((int)cb2.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, man, but i'm a bit confused... I understood the idea, but not how to implement it... would it be "cb2.DataSource = new List<ComboBox> { new ComboBox() { Text = "select course", SelectedValue = 0 } };"??? because when I use "Value" and "ComboBoxItem", the VS returns me an error message